# Count unique occurrences of words from a column in one dataframe in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with a string column `Posts`, something like this:

```
df['Posts']
0       this is an example sentence
1       this too is an example too is an example sentence
2       yup, still an example sentence
```

I have another dataframe `df1` which has the list of tags in a column `Phrases`, something like this:

```
df1['Phrases']
0       example
1       example sentence
2       is an
3       is an example
4       yup
```

I need a dataframe which has the unique count of `Phrases` in `df1` appearing in `df`'s `Posts`, something like this:

```
        Phrases             Count   
0       example               3 
1       example sentence      3
2       is an                 2
3       is an example         2
4       yup                   1
```

Comment: All tags are one word? Or possible multiple words for one tag?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear and thank you for clarifying. Yes, there are possibilities of multiple words, I've edited the post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), then check non missing values and count occurences by `sum` - `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
df1['Count'] = [df['Posts'].str.extract('(' + x + ')', expand=False).notnull().sum()
                     for x in df1['Phrases']]
print (df1)
               Tags  Count
0           example      3
1  example sentence      3
2             is an      2
3     is an example      2
4               yup      1
```

---

EDIT:

For not count partail match use word boundaries:

```
df1['Count'] = [df['Posts'].str.extract(r'(\b' + x + r'\b)', expand=False).notnull().sum()
                     for x in df1['Phrases']]
print (df1)
            Phrases  Count
0           example      3
1  example sentence      3
2             is an      2
3     is an example      2
4               yup      1
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for your answer. When I try your code, I find that it is counting partial matches too. For instance, if I were to count the number for 'exam', it counts the occurrences of 'example' too. Please help.